# Mocking ControllerContext.IsChildAction throws exception in ParentActionViewContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, moq

I have an ASP.Net MVC method in controller:

```
public ActionResult Update()
{
    if(!ControllerContext.IsChildAction)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Details","Project");
    }

    return PartialView();
}
```

I mock IsChildAction so it returns true.

```
var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>(); 
mockControllerContext.SetupGet(m => m.IsChildAction).Returns(true);

YourController controller = new YourController(); 
controller.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;
```

But this change somehow reflect to asp.net mechanism which now expects property ControllerContext.ParentActionViewContext is not null. So when return statement is executed in test it throws Null reference because this property is null.
I can not mock it because it is not virtual :/

Any idea how to inject in Controller Context value for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably have to use `CallBase = true` in your `ControllerContext` moq:

```
var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext> { CallBase = true, };
```

This way you can still setup the `IsChildAction` property but with CallBase equal to true the mock of `ControllerContext` uses real implementation of the `ControllerContext` so the `ParentActionViewContext` should be there.

> Edit:

After a short inspection of mvc-sources i guess that the Null-Reference Exception might be caused by the `ParentActionViewContext` which comes from: `this.RouteData.DataTokens["ParentActionViewContext"] as ViewContext;`.

So try to add `fakeRouteData.DataTokens["ParentActionViewContext"] = fakeViewContext;` to your test.

This worked for me:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    // Arrange
    RouteData fakeRouteData = new RouteData();
    ViewContext fakeViewContext = new ViewContext();
    fakeRouteData.DataTokens["ParentActionViewContext"] = fakeViewContext;

    Mock<HttpContextBase>  httpContextStub = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(httpContextStub.Object, fakeRouteData);

    HomeController controller = new HomeController();
    var mockControllerContext = new Mock<ControllerContext>(requestContext, controller) { CallBase = true, };
    mockControllerContext.SetupGet(m => m.IsChildAction).Returns(true);

    controller.ControllerContext = mockControllerContext.Object;

    // Act
    var res = controller.Update();

    // Assert
    // TODO ...
}
```

*Tested with System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0.*

Comment: Unfortunately this throws exception on return statement "null reference" at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_TempData()". I have tried execute this method in controller as Action to simulate IsChildAction , but also have problems in this case :/

Comment: You are awesome! Now I have 100% coverage ;) I didn't know hot to mock ParentActionViewContext in all my tests and now it is possible ;) Tnx!

Comment: I am glad I could help :).

Answer (score 0):

first install this package from Package Manager Console

> install-package Xania.AspNet.Simulator -Version 1.3.9

The two tests is for each execution path of the Update method.

```
[Test]
public void ChildActionNotInvokedAsChildAction()
{
    var action = new TestController()
        .Action(c => c.Update());

    action.GetActionResult().Should().BeOfType<RedirectToRouteResult>();
}

[Test]
public void ChildActionInvokedAsChildAction()
{
    var action = new TestController()
        .ChildAction(c => c.Update());

    action.GetActionResult().Should().BeOfType<PartialViewResult>();
}
```

Comment: interesting stuff, do you have some documentation how to use it?

Comment: not really, altho i am working on it. I have a lot of example which can be found at github
https://github.com/ibrahimbensalah/Xania.AspNet/tree/simulator.1.3-beta/Xania.AspNet.Simulator

Comment: you can also check out some youtube vids at
https://www.youtube.com/user/mohcine56/videos